# SQL - SELECT ... LIMIT [X] OFFSET [Y] without including a previous record

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

In MySQL, I have a simple SELECT query that sorts posts based on certain criteria (num_likes, num_comments, etc).

In order to load these posts onto my app, I use LIMIT and OFFSET in order to display n amount of posts per page. However, results of the SELECT query can change due to new records being inserted. As a result, it is possible for previous results to reappear in succeeding pages.

Is it possible to prevent this from happening?

Comment: You would need to return all of the results from the query to the app, and handle the pagination from that side, rather than from SQL.

Comment: Are you sure you want to prevent that? Wouldn't you be showing incorrect data, then?

Comment: However, that would be an extremely large amount of data to send. How do sites and apps like Facebook and Instagram do it? Repeating posts don't seem to happen at all. 

The only way I can think of is to create a list of previous IDs in the app and compare it with the IDs in the query to prevent duplicates from occurring.

Comment: I think so. I mean, if I were to go to Reddit, I wouldn't want to see the same results on the next page.

Comment: but here on SO you get results "pushed" if you scroll long enough, so you can get some of them several times.

Comment: @MicoAbrina I can't speak to exactly how Facebook may be doing it, but from pure speculation, it looks like they are storing a list of post ID's per session, and merely expanding it via queries from the earliest point when you scroll too far (as well as notifying you of posts with a more recent ID than the most recent one showed on your session).  This is just speculation though - I don't mess with this sort of development much.

Answer (score 0):

Create a binary-search tree of ID's that appeared in previous queries and compare it with the ID's in the current query. If there are duplicate ID's, don't display those records.

It's a simple O(logn) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to avoid/prevent that from happening. One way to do that is to avoid using **`LIMIT m,n`** (or LIMIT n OFFSET m`), and just use **`LIMIT n`**, along with "saved" values from the last seen row on the prior page.

Mae use of the saved values in the query to get the next page.

Say this query returns the first page of rows to be displayed:

```
  SELECT t.num_likes
       , ...
       , t.id
  ORDER BY t.num_likes DESC, t.id DESC
  LIMIT $pagesize
```

We retain the values of `id` and `num_likes` for the last row, for use in the next query. For the "next" query, we use those values like this:

```
  SELECT t.num_likes
       , ...
       , t.id
   FROM mytable t
  WHERE t.num_likes <= :last_seen_num_likes 
    AND (t.num_likes < :last_seem_num_likes OR t.id < :last_seen_id)
  ORDER BY t.num_likes DESC, t.id DESC
  LIMIT $pagesize
```

For example, if the last row on the page was `num_likes=214` and `id=42`, the query to get the next 50 rows:

```
  SELECT t.num_likes
       , ...
       , t.id
   FROM mytable t
  WHERE t.num_likes <= 214
    AND (t.num_likes < 214 OR t.id < 42)
  ORDER BY t.num_likes DESC, t.id DESC
  LIMIT 50
```

Using this approach essentially retains the position in the list of rows, even when rows are added before. Rather than attempt to re-count to the same position, we're using retained values to preserve our position in the list.

If you want to enable "previous" page functionality, also retain the values from the "first seen" row, and you can run a similar query, just flip the direction of the inequality comparisons.

(What this doesn't address the issue of the value of `num_likes` changing on a row between queries, effectively re-ordering that row in the list.)

Answer (score 0):

Make the id of the last item displayed into one of the parameters for the SQL. Then change your code so that when "next page" is pressed, it returns the first n items after the one in question.